# How to plot pose given by ROBOT_POSE_EKF

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

UBUNTU 12.04 and Fuerte.

I am currently using robot_pose_ekf package to find the pose of the robot equipped with IMU and odometry data.

The graph which is shown in this page is cool.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf

I want to plot in the same way but I am not able to figure out how the graph was plotted.

I tried using rxplot but I was able to plot positions X and Y of one topic in one plot but not both the topics(with EKF and without EKF) in the same plot...I dont want to have time axis too.

Thanks,
Sai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44409/how-to-plot-pose-given-by-robot_pose_ekf/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2012-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not have the exact example handy but you could start from here using Matlab: http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Plotting%20controller%20data%20in%20matlab. You will have to adopt the tutorial in that you will log the "robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined" and "base_odometry/odom" topics. From both datasets you will only be interested in the pose.position.[x|y] values and can then plot them using plot(data.pose.position.x, data.pose.position.y) command. If you merge both datasets you can obviously also create 2 plots. D.

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2012-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1